# How to reduce frequency of continuously fired event's event handling

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am learning about tasks and `async/await` in c#. So please consider the stupidity of my question.

There is an event `DummyEvent` in a class. An event handler `DummyEventHandler` is subscribed to this `event` and it handles a large amount of CPU bound task, which is actually not needed to be used so frequently.

For that reason, if `DummyEvent` is fired continuously, I want `DummyEventHandler` to respond either at a reduced frequency, or respond at the end of that continuity.

So, my idea is to extract the large task into a separate Task and made it to delay 500 millisecond before it proceeds. After the delay ends, it will check whether the same Task has been scheduled again (continuous event fire) or not and avoid the large calculation if true.

Here is my naive implementation of that idea:

```
int ReducedCall = 0;
int TotalCallActual = 0;

protected void DummyEventHandler(object sender, bool arg)
{
    TotalCallActual++;
    LargeCPUBoundTask(); // there is a green underline here, but I think it's ok, or.. is it?
}

async Task LargeCPUBoundTask()
{
    ReducedCall = TotalCallActual;

    await Task.Delay(500);
    // if this task is called again in this time, TotalCallActual will increase

    if (ReducedCall == TotalCallActual)
    {
        // do all the large tasks
        ……

        ReducedCall = 0;
        TotalCallActual = 0;
    }
}
```

But the problem is, I am not getting what I want. The line `Task.Delay(500)` doesn't actually await , or, if it does wait, there is something wrong because I experience staggering .

Any better idea, or any improvement / correction?

Ask for any additional information.

Thanks

Comment: You are talking about the green line under `MyTask` but you did not include any method called that way in your code. And exactly how and when are `TotalCallActual` and `ReducedCall` increased/decreased? And how about creating a code we can actually test?

Comment: @PeterBons sorry for late reply, I have updated my question, `MyTask` is actually `LargeCPUBoundTask`, it was a error while simplifying the question. `TotalCallActual` is increased every time the `DummyEventHandler` is called, with the line: `TotalCallActual++;` and reduced in the event handler.

Comment: It's ok. I've updated my answer

Comment: Since posting my answer, I've created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/clayv/EventReducer) with a solution that includes tests and a sample console app. It is also available via NuGet (search for CVV.EventReducer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) to do this:

```
void Main()
{
    var generator = new EventGenerator();
    var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler<bool>, bool>(
                h => generator.MyEvent += h,
                h => generator.MyEvent -= h);

    observable
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Subscribe(s =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("doing something");
        });

    // simulate rapid firing event
    for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        generator.RaiseEvent(); 

    // when no longer interested, dispose the subscription  
    subscription.Dispose(); 
}

public class EventGenerator
{
    public event EventHandler<bool> MyEvent;

    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        if (MyEvent != null)
        {
            MyEvent(this, false);
        }
    }
}
```

The [`Throttle`](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Throttle) operator as coded above will allow a value (event) getting true every second.

So in the above code example the text *doing something* will only be printed once (after a second) even while the event is fired many times.

**Edit**
By the way, the reason for the green line is that your Task is not awaited. To fix it alter the code to:

```
protected async void DummyEventHandler(object sender, bool arg)
{
    TotalCallActual++;
    await LargeCPUBoundTask(); // there is no more green underline here
}
```

Unfortunately this will still not solve your issue as an event cannot be awaited so if the event is raised again while `LargeCPUBoundTask` is still running another call to `LargeCPUBoundTask` will be made so the work is overlapping if you get what I mean. In other words, that is why your code does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the timer event handler instead of your DummyEventHandler
Just adjust the frequency in milisencond of the timer and that will be it. You can create a timer via code without adding it to a form as a control. I think it is in the common controls lib.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some more time thinking about this problem and the assumption I made with my first solution was that the event is continuously firing, when it could just be firing part of the time for a while and then stop in the *real* problem.

In cases like this, the CPU bound task would only occur on the first event firing and then if the events finish firing before that CPU bound task completes, the remaining events would not get handled.  But you wouldn't want to handle all of them, just the "last" one (not necessarily the actual last one, just one more to take care of the "cleanup").

So I've updated my answer to include the use case where there are frequent yet intermittent (i.e. burst of events then quiet) the correct thing would occur and a final run of the CPU bound task would happen (but still no more than 1 CPU bound task running at a time).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sender s = new Sender();
        using (Listener l = new Listener(s))
        {
            s.BeginDemonstration();
        }
    }
}

class Sender
{
    const int ATTEMPTED_CALLS = 1000000;

    internal EventHandler frequencyReducedHandler;
    internal int actualCalls = 0;
    internal int ignoredCalls = 0;

    Task[] tasks = new Task[ATTEMPTED_CALLS];

    internal void BeginDemonstration()
    {
        int attemptedCalls;
        for (attemptedCalls = 0; attemptedCalls < ATTEMPTED_CALLS; attemptedCalls++)
        {
            tasks[attemptedCalls] = Task.Run(() => frequencyReducedHandler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty));
            //frequencyReducedHandler?.BeginInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty, null, null);
        }
        if (tasks[0] != null)
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Attempted: {attemptedCalls}\tActual: {actualCalls}\tIgnored: {ignoredCalls}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Listener : IDisposable
{
    enum State
    {
        Waiting,
        Running,
        Queued
    }

    private readonly AutoResetEvent m_SingleEntry = new AutoResetEvent(true);
    private readonly Sender m_Sender;

    private int m_CurrentState = (int)State.Waiting;

    internal Listener(Sender sender)
    {
        m_Sender = sender;
        m_Sender.frequencyReducedHandler += Handler;
    }

    private async void Handler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        int state = Interlocked.Increment(ref m_CurrentState);
        try
        {
            if (state <= (int)State.Queued) // Previous state was WAITING or RUNNING
            {
                // Ensure only one run at a time
                m_SingleEntry.WaitOne();
                try
                {
                    // Only one thread at a time here so
                    // no need for Interlocked.Increment
                    m_Sender.actualCalls++;
                    // Execute CPU intensive task
                    await Task.Delay(500);
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Allow a waiting thread to proceed
                    m_SingleEntry.Set();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref m_Sender.ignoredCalls);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_CurrentState);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        m_SingleEntry?.Dispose();
    }
}
```